# How to re-size image without effecting the quality of original image in C#?

Tags: c#, image

How to create a multiple image thumbnails of a image in C#.

**Condition is**:
1. Image quality should not effect.
2. Thumbnails size should be not same.

Comment: And what's the problem? Have you searched/tried anything?

Comment: Do you expect from us writing code for you? That's not how Stackoverflow works. Try something, write some codes and if you stuck any point, come back here..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net mvc then you could try the build-in WebImage class. More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.111).aspx

For more professional use, where you want to control everything, you could use: http://imageresizing.net/ this suite is very advanced with lots of features on image resizing.

There are also plenty of options available for writing your own code, an example can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET

My suggestion would be: "Don't try to invent the wheel again", there are a lot of good solutions out there.

Hope this can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Web.UI;

    /// <summary>
    /// An abstract ImageFilter class.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class ImageFilter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Processes the image with current filter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="image">The image to process.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a Image after applying current filter.</returns>
        public abstract System.Drawing.Image Process(System.Drawing.Image image);

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
        /// </returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Image Filter";
        }
    }



    public class ResizeFilter : ImageFilter
        {
            private int x = -1;
            private int y = -1;

            private int height;

            private int width;

            private InterpolationMode interpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;

            private ResizeMode resizeMode = ResizeMode.Fit;

            [DefaultValue(-1)]
            [Category("Behavior")]
            public int X
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.x;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (value < 0)
                    {
                        value = -1;
                    }

                    x = value;
                }
            }

            [DefaultValue(-1)]
            [Category("Behavior")]
            public int Y
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.y;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (value < -1)
                    {
                        value = -1;
                    }

                    y = value;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether disable transparency.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            ///     <see langword="true"/> if disable transparency; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
            /// </value>
            /// <author>Anwar</author>
            /// <datetime>3/4/2011 5:37 PM</datetime>
            [DefaultValue(false), Category("Behavior")]
            public bool DisableTransparency { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the maximum height of the resulting image.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The height of the resulting image.</value>
            [DefaultValue(0)]
            [Category("Behavior")]
            public int Height
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.height;
                }

                set
                {
                    CheckValue(value);
                    this.height = value;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the interpolation mode used for resizing images. The default is HighQualityBicubic.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The interpolation mode.</value>
            [DefaultValue(InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic)]
            [Category("Behavior")]
            public InterpolationMode InterpolationMode
            {
                get { return this.interpolationMode; }

                set { this.interpolationMode = value; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the resize mode. The default value is Fit.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The image resize mode.</value>
            [DefaultValue(ResizeMode.Fit)]
            [Category("Behavior")]
            public ResizeMode ResizeMode
            {
                get { return this.resizeMode; }

                set { this.resizeMode = value; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the maximum width of the resulting image.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The width of the image..</value>
            [DefaultValue(0)]
            [Category("Behavior")]
            public int Width
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.width;
                }

                set
                {
                    CheckValue(value);
                    this.width = value;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Processes the image with current filter.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="image">The image to process.</param>
            /// <returns>Returns a Image after applying current filter.</returns>
            public override Image Process(Image image)
            {
                int scaledHeight = (int)(image.Height * (this.Width / (float)image.Width));
                int scaledWidth = (int)(image.Width * (this.Height / (float)image.Height));

                switch (this.ResizeMode)
                {
                    case ResizeMode.Fit:
                        return this.FitImage(image, scaledHeight, scaledWidth);
                    case ResizeMode.Crop:
                        return this.CropImage(image, scaledHeight, scaledWidth);
                    default:
                        Debug.Fail("Should not reach this");
                        break;
                }

                return null;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>
            /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
            /// </returns>
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "Resize Filter";
            }

            private static void CheckValue(int value)
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
                }
            }

            private Image CropImage(Image img, int scaledHeight, int scaledWidth)
            {
                int resizeWidth;
                int resizeHeight;

                if (this.Width != 0 && this.Height != 0)
                {
                    resizeWidth = this.Width;
                    resizeHeight = this.Height;
                }
                else if (this.Height == 0)
                {
                    resizeWidth = this.Width;
                    resizeHeight = scaledHeight;
                }
                else if (this.Width == 0)
                {
                    resizeWidth = scaledWidth;
                    resizeHeight = this.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.Width / (float)img.Width > this.Height / (float)img.Height)
                    {
                        resizeWidth = this.Width;
                        resizeHeight = scaledHeight;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resizeWidth = scaledWidth;
                        resizeHeight = this.Height;
                    }
                }

                Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {
                    this.SetupGraphics(graphics);

                    if (this.DisableTransparency)
                    {
                        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, resizeWidth, resizeHeight);
                    }

                    int srcX = this.X;
                    int srcY = this.Y;

                    if (srcX == -1)
                    {
                        srcX = (this.Width - resizeWidth) / 2;
                    }

                    if (srcY == -1)
                    {
                        srcY = (this.Height - resizeHeight) / 2;
                    }

                    graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, resizeWidth, resizeHeight), srcX, srcY, resizeWidth, resizeHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                return newImage;
            }

            private Image FitImage(Image img, int scaledHeight, int scaledWidth)
            {
                int resizeWidth;
                int resizeHeight;

                if (this.Width != 0 && this.Height != 0)
                {
                    resizeWidth = this.Width;
                    resizeHeight = this.Height;
                }
                else if (this.Height == 0)
                {
                    resizeWidth = this.Width;
                    resizeHeight = scaledHeight;
                }
                else if (this.Width == 0)
                {
                    resizeWidth = scaledWidth;
                    resizeHeight = this.Height;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.Width / (float)img.Width < this.Height / (float)img.Height)
                    {
                        resizeWidth = this.Width;
                        resizeHeight = scaledHeight;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resizeWidth = scaledWidth;
                        resizeHeight = this.Height;
                    }
                }

                Bitmap newimage = new Bitmap(resizeWidth, resizeHeight);
                using (Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(newimage))
                {
                    if (DisableTransparency)
                    {
                        gra.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, resizeWidth, resizeHeight);
                    }

                    this.SetupGraphics(gra);
                    gra.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, resizeWidth, resizeHeight);
                }

                return newimage;
            }

            private void SetupGraphics(Graphics graphics)
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = this.InterpolationMode;
            }
        }

////Seprate this enum in your different class ResizeMode.cs
    /// <summary>
        /// Image Resize Modes.
        /// </summary>
        public enum ResizeMode
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Fit mode maintains the aspect ratio of the original image while ensuring that the dimensions of the result
            /// do not exceed the maximum values for the resize transformation.
            /// </summary>
            Fit,

            /// <summary>
            /// Crop resizes the image and removes parts of it to ensure that the dimensions of the result are exactly 
            /// as specified by the transformation.
            /// </summary>
            Crop
        }

///Your Controller Code
    public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Home/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult ImportImage()
            {
                var postedFile = Request.Files["FileUpload1"];
                if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0 )
                {

                    MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();

                    postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);

                    Image image=new Bitmap(ms);

                    Guid newImageName=Guid.NewGuid();
                    string newNameToImage = newImageName.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);

                    ResizeFilter resizeFilter=new ResizeFilter {Height = 0, Width = 75};
                    using (Image thumbnailImage = resizeFilter.Process(image))
                    {
                        var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), newNameToImage);
                        thumbnailImage.Save(imagePath);
                    }
                    resizeFilter.Width = 350;
                    resizeFilter.Height = 0;
                    newImageName = Guid.NewGuid();
                    newNameToImage = newImageName.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                    using (Image middleImage = resizeFilter.Process(image))
                    {
                        var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), newNameToImage);
                        middleImage.Save(imagePath);
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
    ///View Coding
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ImportImage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" id="FileUpload1" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" />
        }
```

Comment: In this code the original file is not saved in your Directory.I am only doing resizing from original image.You can save the original file if you want.